# Sweet Alert with ajax - can't figure out the return message after post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, sweetalert

I want to use sweet alert JS to display alerts on ajax form submit. By doing some research, I have figured out how to post with ajax but can't make it up running properly with sweet alert to display alerts.

> index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="sweet-alert@*" data-semver="0.4.2" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/0.4.2/sweet-alert.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="sweet-alert@*" data-semver="0.4.2" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/0.4.2/sweet-alert.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="form-horizontal" name="addSaleForm" id="addSaleForm" method="POST">
    <label>First Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br>
    <button type="submit" id="submit-btn" name="register">Submit</button>
  </form>

  <!-- Display result/error msg from php file -->
  <div id="status"></div>

</body>

</html>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#addSaleForm").on('submit', (function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      swal({
          title: "Are you sure?",
          text: "Do you want to submit it?",
          type: "warning",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
          confirmButtonText: 'Yes!',
          cancelButtonText: "No!",
          closeOnConfirm: false,
          closeOnCancel: false
        },
        function(isConfirm) {
          if (isConfirm) {
            swal(
            function() {
              $.ajax({
                url: "process.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data) {
                  if (data === 'Success') {
                    swal("Processed!!!", "Your form is processed successfully", "success");
                  }
                  else {
                    document.getElementById("status").className += " alert-danger";
                    $("#status").html(data);
                    swal("Error!!!", data, "error");
                  }
                },
                error: function() {}
              });
            });
          } else {
            swal("Cancelled", "Your form is cancelled.", "error");
          }
        });



    }));
  });
</script>
```

> process.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['fname'])) {
  echo "Success";
}
else{
  echo "Please enter your first name.";
}
?>
```

And here's a live version of the above code.
http://plnkr.co/edit/maZs1NjFlxzqoFpGLgoe?p=preview

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine, but your process.php rejects the form - it expects a 'files' field there ( "message": "files is required").

Comment: @denis: What sort of files?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to parse your response after you were worked it in your php conditions. Just use JSON for return the anwer in your ajax, parse it and then use sweet alert for show a message. Please see this example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Code</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your name">
        <input type="button" id="confirm" value="Confirm">
    </form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('#confirm').click(function() {        
        var name = $('#name').val().trim();
        //We count how many letters have the NAME. If you write MARIO, you will have the number 5, because MARIO have 5 letters
        var name_length = name.length;
        var mydata = 'action=check_name&name='+name+'&length='+name_length;
        $.ajax({
            method:'POST',
            url:'myfile.php',
            data:mydata,
                success:function(response) {
                    var answer = JSON.parse(response);
                    switch ( answer.status_response ) {
                        case 'success' :
                            swal("Good job!", ""+answer.message_response+"", "success")                     
                            break;
                        case 'error' :
                            swal("Stop!", ""+answer.message_response+"", "error")   
                            break;
                    }
                }
        });
    });
</script>
<!--Please load all your sweet alerts files, i will recommed you this version: http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/-->
</body>
</html>

<?php 
    //myfile.php
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch ( $action ) {
        case 'check_name':
            $name = addslashes(trim($_POST['name']));
            /* Also in PHP you can to delete spaces in the name you recieve for determinate if you not are recieving only spaces in the name
            * $name_length = $_POST['name_length'];
            */

            //strlen is for count all letters in your string for $name
            $count_name_length = strlen($name);
            //If name have more than 0 letters, you successfully recive real namne
            if ( $count_name_length > 0 ) {
                $response = array(
                                 'status_response'  => 'success',
                                 'message_response' => 'Thank you for write your name, '.$name);
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
            //Otherwise, the user does not provide a name
            else {
                $response = array(
                                 'status_response'  => 'error',
                                 'message_response' => 'Hey, you have to put one name!');
                echo json_encode($response);                
            }
            break;
    }
?>
```